# FileZilla Pro CLI Batch command file not executing

Tags: batch-file, command-line, filezilla

I am currently attempting to use FileZilla Pro CLI on a Windows machine to connect and upload to a site in that is working in the Site Manager.

The issue is, the command below works perfectly when pasting it directly into the cmd line. However when saving it as a batch file, it simply just gets to the `fzcli>` prompt and then nothing happens.

The two line breaks are on purposes to override the requirement for a password and it works perfectly when pasted in.

Does anyone know if this is a cmd line issue, or if my commands need to be different to work in batch file mode?

```
fzcli
connect --site 0testsite01


put C:/inetpub/wwwroot/websites/sftp/files/customer/test-01.txt /test-sftp/testuser01/test/test-01-uploaded.txt
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Your batch file executes `fzcli` in an interactive mode. The `fzcli` then waits for you to interactively enter the commands. Only after you would exit the `fzcli`, the batch file would continue. And fail, as it will try to execute `connect` as a batch file command. The `fzcli` does not know about the batch file. Nor does the batch file interpreter know about the `fzcli` commands.

It's a common misconception. You will find plenty of similar questions basically about scripting any tool that has its own commands. For example: [`sftp`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38660441/850848), [`ftp`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17115621/850848), [`psftp`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16439039/850848), [`winscp`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31945476/850848).

---

To provide commands to `fzcli`, it seems that you need to use `--script` switch. The `fzcli` documentation gives this example:

```
fzcli --mode standalone --script C:\Scripts\script-file
```